# DataGrid Context Menu Not Binding Properly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, icommand

I have a `DataGrid` to which I am trying to add a `ContextMenu` with a command binding.  The `ContextMenu` is defined like so:

```xml
<DataGrid Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Name="DgResults" Margin="10, 25, 10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding GenerateDutyCycleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                          Header="Generate DC"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

And in the code-behind for the `Window` I have the command property defined:

```cs
        private ICommand? _command;

        public ICommand GenerateDutyCycleCommand
        {
            get
            {
                var m = 0;
                return _command ??= new CommandHandler(GenerateDutyCycle, CanExecute);
            }
        }

        public void GenerateDutyCycle()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
            var selectedItem = DgResults.SelectedItem;
            var p = 0;
        }

        public bool CanExecute()
        {
            return Results.Count > 0;
        }
```

From the XAML if I right click on `GenerateDutyCycleCommand` and select **Go To Definition**, it goes the the property as expected, so it *seems* like everything is correct.

When I run the code though, the `ContextMenu` is always shown and the `CanExecute` method is never hit.  Similarly, if I click on the menu item the `GenerateDutyCycle` method is never hit (or the message box shown).  I have tried several modifications (e.g., setting the `DataContext` of the `MenuItem` to the `Window`) without success.

I also see while running that there is a XAML Binding Failure which states *Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1'*.  I am not clear on why this binding is failing if it can identify the definition (via **Go To Definition**).

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.  TIA.

**UPDATE:**  I was able to get this *partially* working by removing the `ContextMenu` definition from the `DataGrid` and adding a style (to `Window.Resources`) like so:

```xml
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                            Path=DataContext}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, 
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding GenerateDutyCycleCommand}"
                                  Header="Generate DC"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

With this style, when there are no results in the `DataGrid` then the `ContextMenu` is not shown.  However, the breakpoints in the `CanExecute` and `GenerateDutyCycle` methods still do not get hit.  In addition, when there are results and the menu item is clicked, the `MessageBox` is not shown.

Comment: Try this context menu settings like `<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding GenerateDutyCycleCommand}" Header="Generate DC"></MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.  I managed to get the visibility of the context menu to partially work by using a style.  I have updated the original question with these changes for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by adding the `ContextMenu` as a resource of the `DataGrid` and then assigning it in the row's style like so:

```xml
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="CtxDataGrid">
                    <ContextMenu.Items>
                        <MenuItem
                            Header="Generate DC"
                            Command="{Binding GenerateDutyCycleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu.Items>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CtxDataGrid}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```